# What does "work on side gigs" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the context:
"Employees who remained at Yahoo struggled to motivate themselves amid all the uncertainty. Some worked on side gigs in the office. Many feared more layoffs, with or without a sale."

source: [money.cnn.com](http://money.cnn.com/2016/07/25/technology/Yahoo-marissa-Mayer-what-went-wrong/index.html)

Comment: A side-gig is something you do in addition to your regular job.

Comment: This question is [dupe posted on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/what-does-work-on-side-gigs-mean). Please **pick one** site when you post your questions. Cross-site duplication is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

A ***[gig](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gig_1)*** in this context just means "a bit of work"

> 2  - MAINLY AMERICAN a piece of work that you do for money, especially if you are self-employed.

(Macmillan Dictionary)

And so a "side gig" is a bit of work "on the side", meaning "outside your normal employment".

So, it's saying that some of the people were in the Yahoo office, ostensibly working for Yahoo but in fact doing paid work for other clients.